# Code Coverage not working in CLion for linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, code-coverage, clion

I'm new to Clion and Linux, and I've tried running code coverage for branches(like the one VS provide)
Running with coverage results in the following prompt and empty Coverage:

"Coverage data might be incomplete
Process finished with non-zero code"

Running the same project with coverage runs perfectly fine on my windows machine.
These are the flags i'm providing to CMake:

-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="--coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="--coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"

I've also tried following the JetBrains documentation, but it didn't help either.
Gcc and gcov seem to have the same version (11.4.0)

Has anybody else encountered this, and if so, how did you solve it?